# Would it be possible to concoct a "harmful" axiom?

Tags: set-theory, computational-complexity, axioms, formal-systems, automated-theorem-proving

Suppose I run an automated theorem prover. It begins with the axioms of ZFC, and using a random number generator, it proves more theorems, and it runs for two days. At the end of the second day, it halts.

The program then considers all the theorems it proved on the second day (but not the first), and outputs the shortest of these.

Finally, I write a paper proposing the **negation** of the proved statement as a new axiom of ZFC, based on some "deep intuition" I've had.

People spend lots of time working out the "profound consequences" of this new axiom. I spend lots of time laughing, and it ends up taking 100 years for people to work out that the axiom is inconsistent with ZFC.

Could this ever happen? Do the principles of computational complexity allow it to happen? And if so, what can be done about it? I don't want mathematics infected with harmful axioms.

**Edit**: The point is, it may be reasonably easy to use a computer to come up with a harmful axiom, but very difficult to use a computer to refute such an axiom.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few problems with this scenario:

1. I doubt there will be much acceptance of a new axiom without useful consequences (e.g. Martin's Axiom has wonderful consequences, so it was accepted). So before people will accept this as a new axiom, you would have to show why this will be a fruitful addition to the current set of axioms of mathematics.
2. I am certain that people will be reluctant to accept axioms from a stranger. There is a lot to work out with the current axioms, and you would probably have to establish a name before a new axiom that you suggest will be accepted.
3. If you are not a stranger to set theorists, and you are in the status where you could propose some new axiom and people will find it interesting immediately, then it is most likely that you have spent the last decade or more working hard on set theory, and proposing a false axiom on purpose would put your life's work into question. Despite mathematicians (and logicians) having a reputation for being crazy, they are not that kind of crazy.
4. Some of the brightest people I know are set theorists. The fact that you used an automated prover does not mean that people won't be able to see right through that and within a few days, or weeks, or months, point out the contradictions.

But sure, you can always suggest anything that you want. The question is whether or not it is going to stick with set theory. And taking the negation of some randomly proved theorem does not seem like a very fruitful proposition. If it won't be useful to begin with (and you would have to supply the first round of usefulness, and it would have to be *good*), then people won't bother with it.

Comment: Note that this new axiom would be maximally fruitful (just like $0=1$).

Comment: @Arthur: Yes, but then it would be obviously inconsistent. You want to hide the inconsistency...

Comment: But that's his point: A new axiom known (by him and his ATP) to be inconsistent with ZFC, but difficult for humans to discover this.

Comment: @Arthur: Yes, and that's my point. If the new axiom is not obviously inconsistent; then for *other* people to accept it, the one suggesting the axiom would have to give some remarkable uses for it. But in doing so either the proofs would reveal the inconsistency, or they will have to be very difficult to come up with. If one is in a position to suggest a new axiom without doing all that hard work, then one won't suggest a harmful axiom.

Comment: Indeed MA has useful consequences, but it is also relatively consistent with ZFC. That is probably a better reason for accepting MA than that it is useful, although its consistency is still dependent on the consistency of ZF.

Comment: @William: Yes, of course that what nailed the coffin shut was the proof of equiconsistency; but the fact people bothered with this axiom to begin with because it was useful. I can suggest a million new axioms, none of which are [currently] useful. Would anyone bother to verify their relative consistency? Probably not.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a longish comment, but we do not know if ZFC is itself consistent to begin with.  Most set-theorists (if not mathematicians in general) have a strong belief that ZFC is consistent — in part due to the fact that many brilliant mathematicians have not found a contradiction yet — but a belief is all it is.

Could an automated theorem prover come up with a theorem whose negation could not easily be refuted by humans?  Most likely, since automated theorem provers can make connections that are not immediately obvious to humans (consider the [Robbins Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robbins_algebra) which stood open for more than 60 years until William McCune used an automated theorem prover to solve it).  Might it take decades of research to discover the inconsistency?  Perhaps.  Unless, of course, if someone decided to input this all into an automated theorem prover.

Comment: With regards to your last sentence, consider the "edit" at the end of my question.

Comment: But refuting the negation of a theorem is the same as proving the theorem.  If an ATP can prove $ZFC \vdash \phi$ then clearly that same ATP can prove that $ZFC + \neg \phi$ is inconsistent.

Comment: Yes, that same ATP can refute the axiom. But remember, there's randomness involved. Perhaps it would take a very, very long time to refute it.

Comment: So I guess my question is really about computational complexity. Is it the case that there exist harmful axioms that are easy to come up with, but difficult to refute?

Comment: You seem to be getting quite close to [proof complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_complexity), which is unfortunately an area I am not very familiar with.